# Easiest way to experiment with `import` ES6

Tags: node.js, import, ecmascript-6

The recent *Meteor* tutorials use the `import` aspect of ES6 a lot, and I'd like to know if there's an es6 wrapper or other simple way to experiment with this specific feature without having to create a new `package.json`, `npm install babel --save`, `npm start`, etc...

Ideally, something like this:

```
> echo 'import "./importme.js";' > new.js
> echo 'console.log('hi');'      > import.js
> es6 new.js
hi
>
```

I did notice *babel-node*, but it's complaining that import is not a valid token, and apparently it doesn't support `import` from the REPL.

Is there a REPL or node wrapper that supports `import`?

Thanks

Comment: [ts-node](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ts-node).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`babel-node` will work fine, but `babel` doesn't do anything out of the box since version 6. You have to install presets to opt-in to the new features.

1. `npm install babel-node`
2. `npm install babel-preset-es2015` Installs the preset for ES2015 syntax.
3. `touch .babelrc` Create a .babelrc file to tell `babel` which presets you are using

Inside your `.babelrc` file, add the following code:

```
{
  "presets": ["es2015"]
}
```

Now, running `babel-node` will work.

Comment: It worked!  Modules aren't supported from the REPL, but it's pretty simple this way!

Answer (score 0):

I believe that there is not, in fact, a simpler and more maintainable way than what is presented in the Babel 6 manual.  It is not too hard.  See https://babeljs.io/docs/setup/#installation